# While using system.data.sqlclient the same program will connect on one box but not another to same SQL Server R2 2008 running on a 3rd box

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Let me see if I can ask this question with right information that does not get us off into the weeds. First let me define a system... (IP are internal WAN only, not public facing) The 10.29.5.x subnet can route to 192.168.60.x subnet.

*Box 1 running Win 7 64 bit SQL Server R2 2008 IP address 192.168.60.71/24

Box 2 running Win 7 64 bit SQL Server R2 2008 IP address 10.29.5.70/24

Box 3 running XP    32 bit                    IP address 10.29.5.74/24

Connect String is :Initial Catalog=Iris;Persist Security Info=False;connect timeout= 10;user ID=xxxxx_Programer;password=xxxxxPassword;Data Source=192.168.60.71;Asynchronous Processing=True*

The program is using system.data.sqlclient (vb.net). If I run it on Box 2, it connects ok, if I run it on Box 3 it errors.

Error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 -
>   Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

I am assuming there is not a network, firewall, code, or configuration issue since I can connect from box 2 to box 3. I loaded the SQL Management Studio down on box 3 and tried to connect to box 1, and it worked. 
I am thinking it something to do with .Net framework since I can connect with SQL Management Studio. Box 3 in production will not have it. BTW, 4.0 is the targeted framework. 
Let me start here and see where the questions lead, I can give more detail if necessary.

Comment: Is Windows Firewall running on Box 3?  If yes, have you made sure that it allows your program to make outgoing connections, or have you disabled it to test?  SQL Management Studio would have created rules for Windows Firewall to allow it to make outgoing connections, so just because that works doesn't mean that it's not blocking your program.

Comment: .NET have nothing to do with that. Check if your application allowed to create outgoing connections

Comment: Yes, I have tried to disable firewall, but as Fabio mention, They should be the same. Again Box 3 is an 32 bit XP box. I have some assemblies that are X86 so I have to build the whole app as X86. But the exact same build runs on Box 2 which is 64 bit Win7. How would **system.data.sqlclient** connect different than SQL Studio? Just for grins I did try and build using ANYCPU, no difference as far as connecting.

Answer (score 0):

if you use user and password, then "Persist Security Info=True"

Missing "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" in connection string.

Try create "sql.udl" file and test different configuration.